# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER chain step that's always executed

Tags: oracle11g, chain, dbms-scheduler

I have a chain, that consists of about 20 steps. One of the final steps is a shell script, that sends report by e-mail. Is there a way to run this step always - no matter if some of the previous steps failed or not? Writing a rule for that step like `step1 SUCCEEDED or step1 FAILED ... or stepn SUCCEEDED or stepn FAILED` doesn't seem like a good solution...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `step1 completed and step2 completed ... `   completed = 'SUCCEEDED, FAILED, or STOPPED'

Comment: thanks, i can actually just make a rule for the last step with status "COMPLETED" as you suggested, because my chain doesn't have parallel branches, but is there a way to execute the last step if ANY of the previous steps have status "FAILED"?